# Resharper Quick tips no longer accessible in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have a `switch` statement in my code and I'm looking to convert it to a `if/else`. IMHO Resharper was providing such a feature and this was possible using the quick-tip icon (light bulb / hammer tool).

The quick-tip icon still appears, but when I click on it, nothing happens.
Here's what it looks like when I have the cursor on the `switch` statement:

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried:

- clear Resharper caches and restart Visual Studio
- upgrade Visual Studio to 15.9.12 and restart
- disable Resharper, restart VS, enable Resharper, restart VS

What can I do to make the quick tip work again?

Resharper version: 2018.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing Resharper installation via control panel worked, the refactoring is now available:

[image: Screenshot]